# What are the implications of reseting an iOS distribution certificate in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xcode8

I have inherited an iOS project that has an app currently submitted to the App Store. I want to release a new beta version of an app. After I Archive the app in the Xcode and try to Validate it, it shows the following message shown on the screenshot:

> Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets. Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate.

I don't have the distribution certificate locally and don't have access to the computer that had it. As far as I understood form other questions, one option is to click the "Reset" button. What are the implications of reseting the distribution certificate? Will it affect the current app in the App Store? Will other services like Push notifications and in-app purchases continue to work in the current app?

[image: Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reseted the distribution certificate and it did not affect the published version of the app. Push notifications continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting Certificates Using Xcode
If Xcode detects an issue with a signing identity, it displays an appropriate action in Accounts preferences. If Xcode displays a Create button, the signing identity doesn’t exist in your developer account or on your Mac. If Xcode displays a Reset button, the signing identity is not usable on your Mac—for example, it is missing the private key. If you click the Reset button, Xcode revokes and re-creates the corresponding certificate.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

As per my experience, according to Apple support revoking certificate will not have any effect on the uploaded build on iTunes or on live.

https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/
iOS Distribution Certificate (App Store)
If your Apple Developer Program membership is valid, your existing apps on the App Store will not be affected. However, you will no longer be able to submit new apps or updates to the App Store.